# Unable to use Scss variables

Tags: css, sass

I am using cli for sass.

this is my _variable.scss file

```
$black : rgb(50,50,50);
$white : ghostwhite;
$link : red;

$theme_color_1 : lightskyblue;
$theme_color_2 : dodgerblue;
```

this is my main scss file

```
@use "./resources/1-variables/variables";
@use "./resources/2-functions/functions";
@use "./resources/2-functions/mixins";
@use "./resources/3-layouts/layouts";
@use "./resources/4-tools/tools";
@use "./resources/5-components/header";
```

Now if I add some styles in my _variable.scss like

```
body{
    background:red;
}
```

it works however when I use variables in them it doesnt and throws this error
[image: Error]

But if i use

```
@use "./resources/1-variables/variables" as var;
```

and in my main file

```
body{
    background:var.$white;
}
```

it works however, I want to use my variables in all the files like functions, layouts and mixins.

I am new to sass and have gone through numerous stackoverflow questions still no luck.

Comment: shouldn't `@use` be `@import`?

Comment: @superDJ Yes ...  ```@import``` solves the problem but I just learned that @import is deprecated !! that's why thought of using @use

Comment: @kalpeshshende `@import` is not deprecated. It is in the process of being phased out, since LibSass and RubySass do not yet support `@use`, `@import` will still work.

Answer (score -1):

[image]try using

```
@import "./resources/1-variables/variables"
```

Comment: ```@import``` solves the problem but I just learned that @import is deprecated !! that's why thought of using ```@use```

Comment: Did you check the file path?

Comment: yes i did check the file path ... and since other styles are working ... i guess path is correct!!

Comment: how is your file name looks like? variables.scss or _variables.scss, try second one

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the file order?

Comment: did you try with removing resources?
are you calling this inside master.scss file?
@use "./1-variables/variables"